# getting unreachable statement

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have made this app before.and it worked just fine.
but now i am trying to make it with swipe views.
now i m getting these problems.

this is my fragment class

public class currencyclass extends Fragment{

```
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container , Bundle savedInstanceState){
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.currency , container , false);
    return rootView;
```

//i have "unreachable statement" error in only this "editmeter" line

```
    final EditText editmeter = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editMeter);
    final EditText editinch = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editInch);
    final EditText editcentimeter = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editCentimeter);
    final EditText edityard = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editYard);
    final EditText editfeet = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.editFeet);
    TextView textmeter = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textMeter);
    TextView textinch = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textInch);
    TextView textcentimeter = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textCentimeter);
    TextView textyard = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textYard);
    TextView textfeet = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.textFeet);
    TextView button = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);



    Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "CoffeeHouse.ttf");
    textmeter.setTypeface(font);
    textinch.setTypeface(font);
    textcentimeter.setTypeface(font);
    textyard.setTypeface(font);
    textfeet.setTypeface(font);
    button.setTypeface(font);

    editmeter.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonconvert = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
                buttonconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                                         double meter = Double.valueOf(editmeter.getText().toString());
                                                         double inch = meter * 39.3701;
                                                         editinch.setText(String.valueOf(inch));
                                                         double centimeter = meter * 10.0;
                                                         editcentimeter.setText(String.valueOf(centimeter));
                                                         double yard = meter * 1.0936;
                                                         edityard.setText(String.valueOf(yard));
                                                         double feet = meter * 3.2808;
                                                         editfeet.setText(String.valueOf(feet));

                                                     }

                                                 }
                );

            }else{

            }

        }
    });
    editinch.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonconvert = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
                buttonconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                                         double inch2 = Double.valueOf(editinch.getText().toString());
                                                         double meter2 = inch2 * 0.0254;
                                                         editmeter.setText(String.valueOf(meter2));
                                                         double centimeter2 = inch2 * 2.54;
                                                         editcentimeter.setText(String.valueOf(centimeter2));
                                                         double yard2 = inch2 * 0.0277778;
                                                         edityard.setText(String.valueOf(yard2));
                                                         double feet2 = inch2 * 0.0833333;
                                                         editfeet.setText(String.valueOf(feet2));
                                                     }

                                                 }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });

    editcentimeter.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonconvert = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
                buttonconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                                         double centimeter3 = Double.valueOf(editcentimeter.getText().toString());
                                                         double meter3 = centimeter3 * 0.01;
                                                         editmeter.setText(String.valueOf(meter3));
                                                         double inch3 = centimeter3 * 0.393701;
                                                         editinch.setText(String.valueOf(inch3));
                                                         double yard3 = centimeter3 * 0.0109361;
                                                         edityard.setText(String.valueOf(yard3));
                                                         double feet3 = centimeter3 * 0.0328084;
                                                         editfeet.setText(String.valueOf(feet3));
                                                     }

                                                 }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });
    edityard.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonconvert = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
                buttonconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                                         double yard4 = Double.valueOf(edityard.getText().toString());
                                                         double meter4 = yard4 * 0.9144;
                                                         editmeter.setText(String.valueOf(meter4));
                                                         double centimeter4 = yard4 * 91.44;
                                                         editcentimeter.setText(String.valueOf(centimeter4));
                                                         double inch4 = yard4 * 36;
                                                         editinch.setText(String.valueOf(inch4));
                                                         double feet4 = yard4 * 3;
                                                         editfeet.setText(String.valueOf(feet4));
                                                     }

                                                 }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });
    editfeet.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus){
                Button buttonconvert = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.buttonConvert);
                buttonconvert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                     @Override
                                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                                         double feet5 = Double.valueOf(editfeet.getText().toString());
                                                         double meter5 = feet5 * 0.3048;
                                                         editmeter.setText(String.valueOf(meter5));
                                                         double centimeter5 = feet5 * 30.48;
                                                         editcentimeter.setText(String.valueOf(centimeter5));
                                                         double yard5 = feet5 * 0.333333;
                                                         edityard.setText(String.valueOf(yard5));
                                                         double inch5 = feet5 * 12;
                                                         editinch.setText(String.valueOf(inch5));
                                                     }

                                                 }
                );

            }else{

            }
        }
    });



}
```

}

Comment: move `return rootView;` line at end of method

Comment: You mean the line after `return rootView;` is unreachable?  Perhaps you could think about why.

Answer (score 3):

The return keyword signifies the last line of the method. It forces your method to return the value of rootView, all lines below that will never be reached.
This is why the return statement should be the last statement of the method, unless it is within a conditional block.